Typing of the `__getitem__` method of numpy array subclasses
Let's consider a subclass of numpy's ndarray class:
import numpy as np

class ArraySubClass(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array: np.ndarray):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        return obj

Then, taking a slice of an ArraySubClass return an object of the same type, as explained in the documentation:
>>> type(ArraySubClass(np.zeros((3, 3)))[:, 0])
<class '__main__.ArraySubClass'>

So far so good, but I start getting unexpected behavior when I use the static type checked pyright, as seen with the example below:
def f(x: ArraySubClass):
    print(x)

f(ArraySubClass(np.zeros((3, 3)))[:, 0])

The last line raises an error from pyright:
 Argument of type "ndarray[Any, Unknown]" cannot be assigned to parameter "x" of type "ArraySubClass" in function "f"
  "ndarray[Any, Unknown]" is incompatible with "ArraySubClass"

What causes this behavior? Is this a pyright bug? Is the signature of the __getitem__ method from np.ndarray given by the type hints incorrect? Or perhaps should I override this method in ArraySubClass with the correct signature?

Sounds like the type hint of the result of ndarray.__get_item__ doesn't use generics, so it's not covariant with the self class.

Your test:
>>> type(ArraySubClass(np.zeros((3, 3)))[:, 0])
<class '__main__.ArraySubClass'>

Shows that the concrete result of ArraySubClass(np.zeros((3, 3)))[:, 0] is indeed an ArraySubClass, so your expectation that this shouldn't cause trouble makes sense:
def f(x: ArraySubClass):
    print(x)

f(ArraySubClass(np.zeros((3, 3)))[:, 0])

However, f specifically expects an ArraySubClass, and a linter won't be running the code to see what x ends up being. It has to rely on type hints to figure out what x could be.
Since x is the result of ArraySubClass(np.zeros((3, 3)))[:, 0], this means that you are calling __getitem__ on ArraySubClass(np.zeros((3, 3))), and that's defined as (for ndarray):
def __getitem__(self, key: (
    NDArray[integer[Any]]
    | NDArray[bool_]
    | tuple[NDArray[integer[Any]] | NDArray[bool_], ...]
)) -> ndarray[Any, _DType_co]: ...

So, all pyright knows is that a ndarray[Any, _DType_co] will come out. This is true, but the information that this ndarray (in this case) is also a ArraySubClass is lost, pyright cannot tell.
Like user @barmar pointed out in the comments, this could have been prevented if __getitem__ was implemented with generics, making it clear to Python (and the linter) that not only is it true that what comes in is a NDArray and what comes out is ndarray[Any, _DType_co], but in fact that what comes out is the same type of NDArray.
But it hasn't been, possibly for good reason. (I'm not stating an opinion, I'm just saying I haven't looked into the code or documentation more deeply to divine if there is indeed a good reason)
